# How do I make Fastlane Deliver work for tvOS?

Tags: continuous-integration, app-store-connect, tvos, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

Upload to iTunesConnect fails with the following error:

> "Invalid Provisioning Profile. This provisioning profile is not compatible with iOS apps."

```
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------+
|                    deliver 2.26.1 Summary                     |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------+
| username              | iosdev@inspirato.com                  |
| ipa                   | /Users/vagrant/deploy/InspiratoTV.ipa |
| skip_screenshots      | true                                  |
| skip_metadata         | true                                  |
| force                 | true                                  |
| app_identifier        | com.inspirato.travel.InspiratoTV      |
| screenshots_path      | ./screenshots                         |
| metadata_path         | ./metadata                            |
| app_version           | 1.0                                   |
| edit_live             | false                                 |
| platform              | ios                                   |
| skip_binary_upload    | false                                 |
| submit_for_review     | false                                 |
| automatic_release     | false                                 |
| overwrite_screenshots | false                                 |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

It appears that the platform is stuck on "ios" even though I don't have an iOS related app for this bundle ID. I've tried adding "--platform tvOS" to the end of the `$ fastlane deliver ...` command with no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deliver uses the notation "appletvos" for the tvOS platform.

---

Add that to the end of the `$ fastlane deliver` command:

```
$ fastlane deliver ... ... "--platform" "appletvos"
```

Or add it to your .Deliver file like so:

```
deliver(platform: "appletvos")
```

Comment: it works, not officially supported, but it works! Thank you @Justin Valley :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `upload_to_testflight`, please, specify `appletvos` as an app platform

```
upload_to_testflight(app_platform: "appletvos")
```

And don't forget to set `build(include_bitcode: true)` during the build.

If you use `match` for signing specify a `platform` parameter:

```
match(platform: "tvos")
```

If you use a repository for match add a **_tvos** suffix to your provisioning profile name. For example, file

```
profiles/appstore/AppStore_com.yourcompany.youproject.mobileprovision
```

must be renamed to

```
 profiles/appstore/AppStore_com.yourcompany.youproject_tvos.mobileprovision
```

This is necessary to avoid an error with `match`/`sigh`.